# Как из базы вставить данные в форму?

Tags: php

Собственно есть форма , в ней поля ввода. Через нее я заношу данные в БД , все ок. Но вот например если мне нужно отредактировать данные, как эти данные получить из базы я знаю. Но как их вставить в эту же форму, увы. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Просто получаешь данные из базы и в полях (атрибут value) вставляешь их с помощью echo например. Наверное так...

Comment: @Денис Евра и @Олег Б

не пишите новый код с использованием расширения mysql/

Answer (score 1):

Простой и понятный пример:

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM table WHERE id="'.(int)$_GET['id'].'"';
$res=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
 foreach ($row as $key => $val)
  echo "<input type="text" name="$key" value="$val" />";
```